# how to create a matrix from combinations of elements from two vectors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two vectors `X = [a,b,c,d]` and `Y = [m,n,o]`. I'd like to construct a matrix M where each element is an operation on each pair from X and Y. i.e.

```
M[j,i] = f(X[i], Y[j])

# e.g. where f(x,y) = x-y:
M :=
    a-m     b-m     c-m     d-m
    a-n     b-n     c-n     d-n
    a-o     b-o     c-o     d-o
```

I imagine I could do this with two tf.while_loop(), but that seems inefficient, I was wondering if there is a more compact and parallel way of doing this.

P.S. There is a slight complication that X and Y are in fact not vectors, but R2. i.e. each element in X and Y is itself a fixed length vector, and f(X, Y) performs f() element wise. Plus there is a batch component too.

I.e.

```
X.shape => [BATCH, I, K]
Y.shape => [BATCH, J, K]
M[batch, j, i, k]   = f( X[batch, i, k], Y[batch, j, k] )
                    # e.g.:
                    = X[batch, i, k] - Y[batch, j, k]
```

this is using the python API btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this by increasing rank and using [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting). I still don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it's a heck of a lot better than using tf.while_loop I guess! I'm still open to suggestions / improvements.

```
X_expand = tf.expand_dims(X, 1)
Y_expand = tf.expand_dims(Y, 2)
# now I think M = f(X,Y) will broadcast each tensor to the higher dimension on each axis duplicating the data e.g.:
M = X-Y
```